# character encoding is lost when processing a .txt file of country names with with PHP

Tags: php, encoding, character, country

I am processing a text file of country names from ISO-3166 to extract just the country names into an array. The problem is when I output the array, the special characters for some countries is lost or changed:

```
$country_1 = fopen("./country_names_iso_3166.txt", "r");        
while( !feof($country_1) ) {  // go through every line of file
$country = fgets( $country_1 );
if( strstr($country, ",") )         // if country name contains a comma
    $i = strpos( $country, "," ); // index position of comma
else
    $i = strpos( $country, ";" );   // index position of semicolon
$country = substr( $country, 0, $i );   // extract just the country name
$countries[] = $country;
}
```

So now when I output the array, for example, the second country name should be ÅLAND ISLANDS, however it outputs as LAND ISLANDS... Please advise on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the multibyte-aware string functions instead. mb_strstr(), mb_strpos(), mb_substr() (basically just prefix with `mb_`).

Comment: I think it shouldn't be a case in this exact situation.

Comment: @user839163: How are you viewing the output? Via browser? text editor?

Comment: I output to the web browser with echo or printf, and the output for the special characters with accents is lost/changed. I output the same output to a file with file_put_contents, and the special characters are preserved.

Comment: Every unicode-aware app is going to have different rules on how to treat input, and what they'll use as the default character set.  The browser'll choose one way, whatever editor you're using on the files will choose another.

Comment: I figured it out. The text-file being read from containing the country names and ISO-3166 country codes was not set to UTF-8. PHP was not smart enough to figure that out, so I changed the text-file's character encoding to UTF-8 and the problem is fixed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the stream you are outputting the data is using the same character set as the input file.

(Removed mistake of saying that ISO-3166 is a charset)

Comment: ISO 3166 isn't a character set, it's the ISO spec for country code abbreviates (e.g. 'ca' = canada).

Comment: that's right, ISO-3166 is a specification for country codes, known as a standard. I should have been less ambiguous. It also contains full country names preceding the abbreviations.